# Sitecore Glass mapper and File Field type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, glass-mapper

I have a PDF link on a page, for which I've used File field type in Sitecore. I can get the view to render fine but I can't make the File field type editable. I haven't been able to find any documentation around it either. Could you show me an example of how to make a File Field type editable?

`Editable(Model, x => x.FileField)`

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Sitecore supports the field file type in the page editor.

Answer (score 4):

You use Edit Frame as Sitecore does not support the File field type in Field Render.  http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial14.aspx

Comment: This link doesn't work because Glass Mapper is so horrible with their documentation